# React-Rails: React component not rendering

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I am using the react-rails gem, followed all of the instructions in setup, and I cannot get React to load on the webpage. Screenshot from the React web dev tools:

[image]

Using ruby 2.7.2, Rails 6.1.4.

--

I tried it from a clean install and it worked perfectly. I just can't get it to load in an existing app, and I have tried copying config files in new-app to match existing app, and nothing breaks new-app or gets existing app to work.

If anyone could provide some help, or even just directions to look, I really feel lost here, and I would appreciate it.

Thank you!

**Application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

**HelloWorld.js**

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        Greeting: {this.props.greeting}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string
};
export default HelloWorld
```

***index.html.erb***

```
<%= react_component("HelloWorld") %>
```

***Gemfile***

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.7.2'
gem 'rails'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '4.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false
gem "recaptcha"
gem 'filterrific'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap4'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'flatpickr_rails'
gem 'httparty'
gem "best_in_place", git: "https://github.com/mmotherwell/best_in_place"
gem 'down'
gem 'ruby-mp3info'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'rspotify'
gem 'rss'
gem 'redis'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-batch'
gem "sidekiq-throttled"
gem 'multipart-post'
gem 'rails_autoscale_agent'
gem "rack-timeout"
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
gem 'spicy-proton'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'react-rails'



group :production do
  gem 'sentry-raven'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'squasher'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'rspec-sidekiq'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

***application.html.erb***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="blah" />
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

</head>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  We just ran into something similar after upgrading from  node 16.4 to 18.x

Comment: Hey! Upgrading to ruby 3.0.1, rails 7, and using this guide helped me: https://medium.com/rd-shipit/how-to-set-up-a-rails-7-project-with-react-and-jest-f2e016bfbdf3

I found it easiest to start a new app from scratch then to fix the existing one

Comment: Thanks Jackson.  We've tracked down our issues to breaking changes in React.  Some good info in that post, though.